# Исключить дату из массива по условию

Tags: php, массивы

Есть вот такой массив будних, рабочих дней:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [h] => 28.01.2024
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [w] => 29.01.2024
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [w] => 30.01.2024
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [w] => 31.01.2024
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [w] => 01.02.2024
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [w] => 02.02.2024
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [h] => 03.02.2024
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [h] => 04.02.2024
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [w] => 05.02.2024
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [w] => 06.02.2024
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [w] => 07.02.2024
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [w] => 08.02.2024
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [w] => 09.02.2024
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [h] => 10.02.2024
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [h] => 11.02.2024
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [w] => 12.02.2024
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [w] => 13.02.2024
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [w] => 14.02.2024
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [w] => 15.02.2024
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [w] => 16.02.2024
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [h] => 17.02.2024
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [h] => 18.02.2024
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [w] => 19.02.2024
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [w] => 20.02.2024
        )
)
```

И есть вот такой код, который формирует этот массив:

```
foreach($res_work as $key => $item){
            foreach($item as $k => $v){
                if($k == 'w'){
                    $date[] = $v;
                }
            }
        }
```

Ключи $k == 'h' - holiday выходные, $k == 'w' - work рабочие дни, как мне сделать так, что если сегодня date('d.m.Y') - выходной, то формируем массив будних дней начиная со вторника, ну т.е. со второго рабочего дня?

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил, сам отвечаю:

```
$date_now = date(d.m.Y);
foreach($res_work as $key => $item){
            foreach($item as $k => $v){
                if($k == 'w'){
                    $date[] = $v;
                    if(strtotime($v) > strtotime($date_now)){
                        unset($date[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```